# Israeli restaurant-style falafel and hummus, how do to make?

Tags: hummus

How is authentic Israeli restaurant-style falafel and hummus made?

Is there any secret?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

(yes, I know, I cheat by posting a non-answer)

I don't think that there can be a real answer to that question.

There must be dozens of "authentic" recipes for Falafel and hummus; and I am not talking about westernized variation of the recipe.

In the case of the hummus, maybe the chickpeas are fresh or dry, maybe the olive oil is different (generic vs. cold presse), maybe the lemon is more or less sweet, maybe the tahini is home made versus store bought.

Maybe the mix was blended to a smooth texture or just enough to have chunks in it, maybe it was hand crushed in a mortar?

You see there can be a lot of variation, not just on the recipe, but on the ingredients themselves.

If you want to make hummus and falafel at home, you will need to find a recipe (or, 2, 3 more) that appeals to you, and experiment with it by add more or less of that, or more or less of that other thing so you can discover the recipe that you really like.

Comment: Up voted in spite of the cheeting. Hummus is common from Greece to Israel and perhaps elsewhere. But most recipes I know call for the same general ingredients